# BitBlt - captured pixels are all zero (bgra) when using HDC of another app

Tags: windows, winapi

I can successfully capture parts of the screen using BitBlt and GetDIBits thanks to the code in Nick Nougat's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233848/c-read-pixels-with-getdibits).

Capturing the entire screen or desktop seems to work but when I provide the HDC of an app, it prints weird data (in bgra format).

```
HWND dekstopHWND = GetDesktopWindow();
// prints correct desktop pixels

HWND appHWND = FindWindowA(NULL, "Hello World!"); // working handle of an electron app
//prints 0 0 0 0 as pixels

HWND appHWND = FindWindowA(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad"); // Notepad app
//prints 255 255 255 0 as pixels
```

...

- The function `GetDeviceCaps` says that the electron app supports `BitBlt` and
  the device `TECHNOLOGY` is `raster display`.
- The width of the app's DC is always full screen, independent of the window size: `printf("width %d\n", GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(appHWND), HORZRES)); //1920`, is that correct behaviour?

I'm very new to Windows API... Which one of the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555279/using-bitblt-to-capture-desktop-pixel-colors) or functions can be causing this? 
Thank you.

....

```
HBITMAP GetScreenBmp(HDC hdc) {
    int nScreenWidth = 100;
    int nScreenHeight = 100;
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hOld); // always select the previously selected object once done
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    return hBitmap;
}

int main() {
    HWND appHWND = FindWindowA(NULL, "Hello World!");
    HDC hdc = GetDC(appHWND);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = GetScreenBmp(hdc);

    BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

    // Get the BITMAPINFO structure from the bitmap
    if (0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)){
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    // create the bitmap buffer
    BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

    // Better do this here - the original bitmap might have BI_BITFILEDS, which makes it
    // necessary to read the color table - you might not want this.
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // get the actual bitmap buffer
    if (0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, (LPVOID)lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
        cout << "error2" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", (int)lpPixels[i]);
    }

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    delete[] lpPixels;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: I don't find it at all unusual that the first 25 pixels of the bottom line of a Notepad client window would be all white. You do know that bitmaps are bottom up, right?

Comment: Ok, I've just made the notepad window very small and I get a lot of (0,0,0,0) - black transparent and (255,255,255,0) white transparent pixels... However, some normal pixels showed up with 255 as alpha: (240,240,240,255) - this, I suspect, is the scroll bar. I think I should be checking some bounds then... Any idea how?

Comment: Bitmaps typically ignore the alpha channel. There are only one or two API calls that can make use of them. I certainly wouldn't put any meaning on the values you get back from a DC. If you want to do bounds checking I would use the window client area.

Comment: I think you're right. When I do 1000x1000 screen capture using the notepad handle, it draws the app without the app's top menu and the rest is black. The screenshot of the electron app I want is black completely. I think I might have to access some child "render" window... Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Good point about the child window. Notepad for example has an edit control that contains all the content. You can see the window structure with Spy++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetDC` can be used to take screen shot of the client area in native Win32 applications only. That includes programs like Notepad. Or you can use `GetWindowDC` to take screenshot of the whole window.

But applications made with frameworks such as electron app, QT, WPF... will print black screen in response to `GetDC` or `GetWindowDC`. The only way around it is to make sure the target application is visible and take a screenshot of desktop at the specific coordinates where the target application is at.

Windows GDI functions generally ignore alpha channel. But if you retrieve the screenshot in 32-bit, then `GetDIBits` will set the all alpha values set to 255 (at least in Windows 10).

---

Side note,

Your code has a resource leak because it's calling `ReleaseDC` with the wrong window handle. If you called `GetDC(NULL)` then you end it with `ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc)`, otherwise it should be corrected as follows:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(appHWND);
...
//ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc); <- wrong window handle
ReleaseDC(appHWND, hdc);
```

You can also save the whole image instead of printing one byte at a time. Example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    //make sure process is DPI aware
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    HWND hwnd_target = FindWindowA("Notepad", NULL);
    if(!hwnd_target)
        return 0;

    //make sure target window is on top
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_target);
    Sleep(250);

    //get hdc of desktop
    HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);

    //copy bits from coordinates of target window
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd_target, &rc);
    int w = rc.right - rc.left;
    int h = rc.bottom - rc.top;
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
    HGDIOBJ oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, rc.left, rc.top, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteDC(memdc);

    //restore the foreground
    SetForegroundWindow(GetConsoleWindow());

    //save to file
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(bi), w, h, 1, 32 };
    std::vector<BYTE> pixels(w * h * 4);
    GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, h, pixels.data(), 
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    std::ofstream fout("filename.bmp", std::ios::binary);
    BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr = { 'MB', 54 + bi.biSizeImage, 0, 0, 54 };
    fout.write((char*)&hdr, 14);
    fout.write((char*)&bi, 40);
    fout.write((char*)pixels.data(), pixels.size());

    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);

    return 0;
}
```