# Screenshots taken with Pywin32 some times get a black imgaes, I think that handle ins't right

Tags: python, winapi, screenshot

```
def window_full_shot(hwnd, gray=0):
    hwnd = get_hwnd(hwnd)[0]
    print(hwnd)
    print(win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd))
    l, t, r, b = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    h = b - t
    w = r - l
    hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
    memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, w, h)
    memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
    memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), srcdc, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    signedIntsArray = bmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (h, w, 4)
    print(type(img))
    srcdc.DeleteDC()
    memdc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindc)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(bmp.GetHandle())
    if gray == 0:
        return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
    else:
        return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
```

I use this code to shot two windows, one could got a right img, another it ins't work, just like that.
[the right code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2TeE.png)
[the bad code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le0A3.png)

Comment: What does [GetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdisplayaffinity) return for the window that produces a blank image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications made with frameworks such as electron app, QT, WPF... will print black screen in response to `GetDC` or `GetWindowDC`.

**The only way around it is to make sure the target application is visible and take a screenshot of desktop at the specific coordinates where the target application is at.**

Windows GDI functions generally ignore alpha channel. But if you retrieve the screenshot in 32-bit, then `GetDIBits` will set the all alpha values set to 255 (at least in Windows 10).

About code sample(C++), please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53404526/11128312

Python code:

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
from ctypes import windll
from PIL import Image
import time
import ctypes

hwnd_target = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator') # used for test 

left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd_target)
w = right - left
h = bot - top

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_target)
time.sleep(1.0)

hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

result = saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), mfcDC, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

im = Image.frombuffer(
    'RGB',
    (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
    bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
saveDC.DeleteDC()
mfcDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hdesktop, hwndDC)

if result == None:
    #PrintWindow Succeeded
    im.save("test.png")
```